# What is `<<-` in R?

Tags: r

What is `<<-` in R?  I know `<-` means *assignment*, but what does `<<-` mean?

Before posting here, I tried searing Google to find out more about the `<<-` operator, but it did not help me.

Comment: I'm sorry but this question is off-topic, and it can't be migrated to SO so it will just be closed.

Comment: @chl, you don't think this would be acceptable on SO?

Comment: @gung Sure, but this user can no longer ask on SO.

Comment: How to find help on R functions that are not plain text: Enclose them in quotes. Like so `?"<<-"` (plenty of explanation there) ... in fact, if you always enclose the function in quotes, it works, so it's a good habit to be in (compare `?if` with `?"if"` to see why even "plain text" isn't sufficient to avoid needing to quote the argument)

Answer (score 10):

It's a non local assignment (use it carefully)

```
a <- 1

foo <- function(){
    a <<- 2
    0
}

foo()

a
## 2
```

That is the replacement occurs in the *nearest enclosing environment* that contains an object of the same name, or the *workspace* (that is the example case) if none do.

Answer (score 4):

It almost means *global assignment* (see whuber's comment, and the linked docs on scoping). So if you assign A the value of 2 using `A <<- 2` within, for example, a function, and then call that function, other functions and the command line can then use the value of A. This has to do with the concept of [*scoping*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoping), and there are [particulars of R's scoping](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Scope-of-variables). In R see help for `assignOps`, and perhaps peruse the reference to the R Language Definition.

Comment: `<<-` is not a truly global assignment: it differs subtly.  It functions as a global assignment only when the target variable `A` does not yet exist in the parent environment (and the parent itself is not the global environment).

Answer (score 2):

To follow up on @LucaBraglia's answer, consider these examples:

```
foo1 <- function(x){
  increment <- x+1
  sqrt      <- sqrt(increment)
  return(sqrt)
}
foo2 <- function(x){
  increment <<- x+1
  sqrt      <- sqrt(increment)
  return(sqrt)
}

> foo1(3)
[1] 2
> increment
Error: object 'increment' not found
> foo2(3)
[1] 2
> increment
[1] 4
```